# Помогите с linq to xml запросом

Tags: c#, xml, linq2xml

Помогите с linq to xml запросом. Есть вот такой xml

```
<Security Version="1.0">
  <Bond SecurityID="1">
    <Name>Arconic Inc. 5.9 01/02/27</Name>
    <EngName>Arconic Inc. 5.9 01/02/27</EngName>
    <Brief>ARNC 5.9 02/01/27</Brief>
    <InstrumentGroup>Bonds</InstrumentGroup>
    <ISIN>US013817AJ05</ISIN>
    <RegNumber></RegNumber>
    <EndServiceDate>1900-01-01</EndServiceDate>
    <Nominal>1000.00000000000000</Nominal>
      <SecStatusList>
          <SecStatus Brief="ДляКвалИнв" Name="Предназначен для квалифицированных инвесторов" SecStatusID="1" SysType="1" SecStatusTypeID="2">
              <DateStart>2019-01-18</DateStart>
              <DateEnd>2050-01-01</DateEnd>
              <Comment />
          </SecStatus>
      </SecStatusList>
  </Bond>
</Security>
```

Есть класс:

```
public class Bonds
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    public string? ISIN { get; set; }

    public string? RegNumber { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string? NameEn { get; set; }

    public decimal? Nominal { get; set; }

    public DateTime? ExpireDay { get; set; }

    public bool? IsQualifiedInvestors { get; set; }
}
```

Написала запрос для всех полей кроме `IsQualifiedInvestors` (если есть узел с Brief="ДляКвалИнв", то тогда проставляем true, иначе - false). Не пойму как правильно его написать.

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(@".\bond.xml");

List<Bonds> bonds = (from _sec in doc.Element("Security").Elements("Bond")
                     select new Bonds
                     {
                         Id = XmlConvert.ToInt64(_sec.Attribute("SecurityID").Value),
                         ISIN = _sec.Element("ISIN").Value,
                         RegNumber = _sec.Element("RegNumber").Value,
                         Name = _sec.Element("Name").Value,
                         NameEn = _sec.Element("EngName").Value,
                         Nominal = XmlConvert.ToDecimal(_sec.Element("Nominal").Value),
                         ExpireDay = XmlConvert.ToDateTime(_sec.Element("EndServiceDate").Value),
                         //IsForQualifiedInvestors
                     }
                    ).ToList();

foreach (var bond in bonds)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}, {2}, {3}", bond.Name, bond.Nominal, bond.BeansId,bond.ExpireDay);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var bonds = (from bond in doc.Element("Security").Elements("Bond")
             select new Bond
             {
                 Id = (int?)bond.Attribute("SecurityID"),
                 ISIN = bond.Element("ISIN")?.Value,
                 RegNumber = bond.Element("RegNumber")?.Value,
                 Name = bond.Element("Name").Value,
                 NameEn = bond.Element("EngName")?.Value,
                 Nominal = (decimal?)bond.Element("Nominal"),
                 ExpireDay = (DateTime?)bond.Element("EndServiceDate"),
                 IsQualifiedInvestors = bond.Element("SecStatusList")?.Element("SecStatus")?.Attribute("Brief")?.Value == "ДляКвалИнв"
             }
            ).ToList();
```

Класс я бы переименовал в `Bond` - всё-таки должно быть единственное число. А коллекция - `bonds`.

Вместо `XmlConvert`, который относится к другому API, в linq2xml принято использовать приведение типов: `(int?)bond.Attribute("SecurityID")`.
Строковые значения тоже можно приводить: `(string?)bond.Element("ISIN")`, но вариант с `.Value` таки короче.

Так как свойства заданы как `nullable`, то используем `?.Value`, `(int?)`, `(decimal?)` и т. д.

Свойство `Name` объявлено `non-nullable`, поэтому, чтобы избежать возможных ошибок, если в XML не окажется такого узла, следует использовать код наподобие:

```
Name = bond.Element("Name")?.Value ?? "",
```

где вместо `""` указать дефолтное значение.

Comment: Brief берется не из Значения Brief, а из узла SecStatusList\SecStatus и дожен быть равен Brief="ДляКвалИнв", т.е. если такой узел с таким значением существует, то true, иначе false.

Comment: @DHel - изменил код